# Is Google Nearby available for desktop / laptop computers?

Tags: google-nearby

Being Wifi / Bluetooth and speakers available in most desktop / laptop devices I wonder if Google nearby could be used in Desktop or even web applications running locally and offline? (No internet connection but Wifi / BT / speakers enabled)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not currently supported. The chrome.copresence API used to provide some of this functionality, but it is being removed for performance reasons.